# Why do I get "command not found" with the NOT operator in a Bash conditional?

Tags: bash, if-statement

if I have

```
if [ ! -e $dir ];
then
 mkdir $dir
fi
```

work, but not

```
[[ ! -e $dir ]] || mkdir $dir
```

why ?

### Edit 0

with `[[ ...` I get

```
 line 34: [[ !: command not found
```

### Edit 1

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (i686-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

### Edit 2

in some case work and some case don't work, two consecutives commands

```
[user@host ~]$ [ -e /tmp ] && date
-bash: [: missing `]'
[user@host ~]$ [ -e /tmp ] && date
mar jun 26 10:05:50 CLT 2012
```

Comment: Use `set -x` to see what's going on. It works for the rest of the world; there's something else going on with your code.

Comment: Are you sure you have the spacing right? This: `if [[! -e $dir ]] ; then echo ok ; fi` gives me this error: `[[!: command not found`. The space is required.

Comment: The fact that "!" is included in the error makes me suspicious -- is that really a regular space character between "[[" and "!", or might it be something else (like a non-breaking space)?

Comment: Are you sure it's Bash? If it's a Bourne shell (e.g. dash) that doesn't support `[[`, you'll get that error. Make sure your shebang says `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: I don't know what locale is used in the Mariana Islands, but is it possible that you have hidden characters rather than spaces? Bash *requires* spaces around the square brackets; some characters that look like spaces but aren't may cause you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially after edit 2, this really looks to me like a problem with "funny" characters, either nonprinting characters getting mixed in, or normal-looking-but-weird characters like nonbreaking spaces.  These can be fairly hard to detect; things can look completely normal in an editor, and even if you view a script with something like `cat -v` it won't always show funny characters clearly.  If you have `xxd` on your system, it's a really good way to see precisely what's in the file.  Here's a quick demo of this type of problem:

```
$ cat -v nbsptest 
#!/bin/bash -x
[ -e /tmp ] && date
[ -e /tmp ] && date
[ -e /tmp ] && date
$ ./nbsptest 
+ '[ -e' /tmp ']'
./nbsptest: line 2: [ -e: command not found
+ '[' -e '/tmp ]'
./nbsptest: line 3: [: missing `]'
+ '[' -e /tmp ']'
+ date
Sat Jun 30 10:53:56 PDT 2012
$ xxd nbsptest 
0000000: 2321 2f62 696e 2f62 6173 6820 2d78 0a5b  #!/bin/bash -x.[
0000010: c2a0 2d65 202f 746d 7020 5d20 2626 2064  ..-e /tmp ] && d
0000020: 6174 650a 5b20 2d65 202f 746d 70c2 a05d  ate.[ -e /tmp..]
0000030: 2026 2620 6461 7465 0a5b 202d 6520 2f74   && date.[ -e /t
0000040: 6d70 205d 2026 2620 6461 7465 0a         mp ] && date.
```

The script looks completely normal with `cat -v` (and `more`, `vi`, etc), but the first two commands fail.  `xxd` shows why: the first command has a UTF-8 nonbreaking space between the `[` and the `-e` (this shows as c2a0 in the hex listing, `[..-e` in the text listing) and the second command has a nonbreaking space between `/tmp` and `]` (`/tmp..]` in the text listing).

The `-x` display (I used `bash -x` to invoke it, you can also use `set -x` as @CodeGnome suggested) also gives a hint about what's going on.  For the first command, it listed it as `'[ -e' /tmp ']'` -- note the quotes around `[ -e`, which indicates that the shell is treating that all as one "word", which means it doesn't think that's a space in the middle of it.  Similarly, the second command is displayed as `'[' -e '/tmp ]'` with the quotes indicating that it thinks `/tmp ]` is all one "word".

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
[ ! -e $dir ] && mkdir $dir
```

the single "[" is a shortcut for calling test, so the test syntax applies. The double "[[" instead uses bash's logic syntax, which is completely different.

And since you want to execute the command if the test returns true, you should use "&&" - the "||" syntax will only run your command if the test returns false.

edit:

checking the bash man page reveals that conditional expressions (what you get with [[) also understand the -e syntax. That section doesn't mention "!" for negating the result, though it works when trying it on the command line. My guess then is that your system may be running a different version of bash from that of the commenters, one that doesn't understand "!" ? The man page for test clearly indicates that "!" is supported, so in your shoes I would first try with [ ] and see if that works before exploring further.

Comment: The test should be the same whether using `\[` or `[[`. There's something else going on with his code.

Comment: There might be a performance reason to prefer [[ over [: the former can be evaluated in the current bash process, whereas the latter requires spawning a child process for test.

Comment: @MyG `[` has been a builtin in most shells for about 15 years.

Comment: `[[` has more features and is more likely to do what you expect

Answer (score 0):

#### The Syntax Works

At least, it works for me. For example:

```
# Inverted logic. Returns false because directory exists.
$ [[ ! -e /tmp ]]; echo $?
1
```

Are you sure you're using Bash? Check your shell and version.

```
$ echo $SHELL $BASH_VERSION
/bin/bash 4.2.10(1)-release
```

#### A Better Approach

Your conditional logic is a bit convoluted. This is a much cleaner syntax for what you want to do:

```
dir=/tmp/foo
[[ -e "$dir" ]] || mkdir "$dir"
```

This is semantically clearer, and expresses the intent without the inverted logic. There may be cases where you need an inverted test, but your example isn't one of them.

Comment: Works for me as well, with bash 4.2.29. Could the negation inside the test be a recently introduced feature? I see nothing to that effect in the CHANGES file, and it would seem a bit strange.

Comment: @MvG `/usr/bin/\[ ! -e /tmp ]; echo $?` returns 1, as well, which argues that the syntax is about as standard as it gets. Other shells and non-GNU `test` might behave differently, I suppose, but it works on ash and dash, too.

Comment: `$ echo $SHELL $BASH_VERSION
/bin/bash 3.2.25(1)-release`